How to make a list from mysql database while using two different tables
One table contains games' series, the other table contains games:
series



id
series_name




1
Alundra


2
Final Fantasy



games



id
game_name
series




1
Alundra
Alundra


2
Alundra 2
Alundra


3
Final Fantasy
Final Fantasy


4
Final Fantasy II
Final Fantasy


5
Final Fantasy III
Final Fantasy



I am able to list the tables on a website using SELECT * FROM series and SELECT * FROM games.
My goal is a list of series with the games that belong to the series listed one under the other on my website:



Series
Games




Alundra
Alundra



Alundra 2






Final Fantasy
Final Fantasy



Final Fantasy II



Final Fantasy III



I tried JOIN, LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN, etc.:
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM series JOIN games ON series.series_name=games.series";
$var = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($var)){
?>

<div class="x1">
  <div> <?php echo $row['series'] ?> </div>
  <div> <?php echo $row['game_name'] ?> </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>

But it did this:



Series
Games




Alundra
Alundra


Alundra
Alundra 2


Final Fantasy
Final Fantasy


Final Fantasy
Final Fantasy II


Final Fantasy
Final Fantasy III



I tried to use the series names as a variable so it could be passed to the second part of the code where I put another SELECT:
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM series";
$var = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($var)){
?>

<?php $const = $row['series_name'] ?>

<div class="x1">
<div> <?php echo $row['series'] ?> </div>

  <?php
  $sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE series = '$const'";
  $var_2 = $conn->query($sql_2);
  while($row_2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($var_2)){
  ?>

<div class="x2">
 <div> <?php echo $row_2['game_name'] ?> </div>
</div>

 <?php } ?>

</div>

<?php } ?>

But it listed only the first series with its games.

What you are trying to do is not trivial because you're trying to carry out an operation that conflicts with what the database is designed to do for you.  What you want is probably a window setup that counts rows in a group, and then you can conditionally clear the game name column when the window group row number is bigger than 1.

You could also do this as a post-processing step for display purposes. The basic join you did gets the correct answer.

Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by PDO or by MySQLi. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough!

Why did you include PHP code in your question if it's about MySQL?

Actually, it works now. In the second SELECT there is a variable var_2. This code was an example, the real code is much more complex. However, I did not realize that in the full code, instead of var_2 there is just var and var is used in the first SELECT statement. I had not noticed it before LOL. So now it works. Both vars seem to have interfered each other.

Tgis is an output formatting question, not a data retrieval question. You must nit do this in sql as it is not suitable for such transformation. Php+html is the way to go.
